# NO MUESTRA DATOS JSON

Tags: php, android, webservice, jsonarray

tengo este inconveniente con WebService.
Actualmente estoy en un proyecto de Android y estoy consumiendo datos a través de JSON en php, pero cuando hago una consulta en mi codigo no muestra nada en pantalla y si intento con otro dato si lo muestra, Cabe destacar que ambos datos si existe registro en la base de datos
[image: Muestro codigo de como esta estructurado, sin embargo funciona con unos cuantos datos]

[image: Aquí si muestra datos]
[image: Aquí sin embargo no muestra nada]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
?>
```

- Esto es para forzar la codificación a `UTF-8` y con el `Content-type: application/json` te mostrara la data en formato `json`
- También puedes configurar tu MySql para almacenar los datos con el formato `UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser porque el texto tenga acentos y requiera ser codificado con utf8

Ejemplo:
para decodificar

```
 $jsArray["Nombre"]=utf8_decode($dato["NOMBRE_COMPLETO"]);
```

o Codifica

```
 $jsArray["Nombre"]=utf8_encode($dato["NOMBRE_COMPLETO"]);
```

Comment: Gracias fue un buena respuesta a mi duda, ya que también influía las comillas que envuelve el nombre del campo de la tabla de esto [' '] a esto [" "].